# Making a 9-coil, 3-phase brushless PCB stator

Tags: pcb-design, brushless-dc-motor, stator

I'm designing a 9-coil, 3-phase PCB stator, and I'm stuck on how to connect the coils together.

They need to be connected in a Wye configuration, but I'm not sure if each phase is supposed to be connected in series or not.

I looked at [Carl Bugeja's PCB stator video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-YDuCqEwuw), and I am confused by how he connected the coils of the same phase together.

How should I connect the coils to finish this design?

[image]

Comment: Minute 8 shows him connecting them in series.

Comment: Should the current be in the same direction? I wasn't sure if Carl was setting it up that way. @StainlessSteelRat

Comment: Series or parallel isn't really the question or the hard or important part, it's the polarity of each coil to determine whether they add up or subtract their effect. Subtracting the effect makes for a rather useless motor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another one of his designs that I have (successfully) referenced.

[image]

Shown is each of the four layers. You can follow each of the phases. For example, phase A (starting at the red top left circle) goes to the red coil, to a via in the middle, where it pops out at the cyan coil, to the via outside the coil, then to the orange layer to the other middle via, to the blue layer, and then routed to the bottom right coil. And so on.

I believe Carl uses this topology for most of his designs.

Source: https://hackaday.io/project/39494-pcb-motor/log/85467-how-i-design-the-pcb-stator

Comment: For someone whos out to tell you all of his secrets, he leaves a lot out.

Comment: After studying this closely for an half hour, I finally understand the inner layer routing. The coils are in series, but the inner coils are also modified so that if they connect on say layer 2, then the order of the connections made will be 1, 3, 4, 2. Thank you so much for sharing this.

Answer (score 3):

For this type of design, the number of poles has to be 2/3 of the number of coils.  Since you are building a nine-coil stator, this implies a six-pole rotor (three north and three south magnets.)

In a six-coil, four-pole motor as @Jarret has shown, the poles have 180 degree symmetry, so each coil must be attached to the coil which is at 180 degrees (opposite).  In this manner, each north (or south) magnet's instantaneous angular relationship to the coils of each phase is identical.  Each coil pair must therefore have the same current, so they must be in series, and the current direction of rotation (clockwise or counter-clockwise) must also be the same for each coil pair.  (By 180 degree symmetry, I mean that if you rotate the rotor 180 degrees, you are magnetically back where you started - a north magnet is in the same location that it was 180 degrees ago).

In your design, the rotor symmetry is 120 degrees, so the three coils for each phase must be in series once again, and the direction of rotation of current must also be the same.  The only difference in the two designs are the number of coils and poles.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

See:
http://bavaria-direct.co.za/scheme/calculator/

Take note of the direction of winding and connections in this, it gets them correct. If you get it wrong, your motor will be very underwhelming or short out your controller.

You can try to work it out yourself from first principles, but you're quite likely to get it wrong. It's quite a mind game of trying to remember/coherently write it down/...

Comment: Answers that are essentially just a link aren't usually very appreciated on here. Copy the relevant stuff from the link and just have the link there as a source.

Comment: While I appreciate stack exchange seems to like long written answers, unique to the site, on this topic the link and calculator is fast more useful to the OP and future readers. I could screenshot the various input parameters and reverse engineer the code but the OP and future readers will learn more, faster, by clicking it and entering 9 slots, and 6 or 8 or 10 or 12 or... poles. The optimum solution, contrary to other answers here the OP will find isn't actually 2/3 the poles to slots.

Comment: EE.SE is also meant to be a long-standing service, where these answers will still be present (and hopefully relevant) decades into the future.  External links typically change or vanish after awhile, which will make such answers useless.  While the link might be useful today, it might be gone tomorrow.